# How Latent Semantic Analysis Handle Semantics

Tags: nlp, latent-semantic-analysis

I have gone through LSA method. It is said that LSA can be used for semantic analysis. But I can not understand how it is working in LSA. Can anyone please tell me how LSA handle semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the vector space model (VSM)?

In LSA you can compute document similarity as well as type (i.e. word) similarity just as you would with the traditional VSM. That is, you compute the cosine between two type-vectors or two document-vectors (actually LSA allows you to compute also type-document similarity).

The problem with the VSM is that the cosine similarity of documents which do not share a single word equals to 0.

In LSA, the singular value decomposition (SVD) reveals latent semantic dimensions which allow
you to compute the cosine similarity between documents with no words in common, but with some common characteristics.

Comment: Thanks :) I highly appreciate your answer. I understood everything. What is unclear is how LSA identify common characteristics between documents as it is just another a mathematical model.

Comment: How to interpret results in LSA is still an open question! Let me recommend you "Handbook of Latent Semantic Analysis" (or maybe you already read it?) which gives a nice overview of LSA.

Comment: Sure :) here is the TOC: http://lsa.colorado.edu/papers/tabcontents.pdf you might be able to find some of the papers on the internet... like this one: http://lsa.colorado.edu/papers/useweb.pdf